# Fill specific regions in geom_violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I fill a `geom_violin` plot in **ggplot2** with different colors based on a fixed cutoff?

For instance, given the setup:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3,each = 100),
                  y = c(rnorm(100,-1),rnorm(100,0),rnorm(100,1)))
dat$f <- with(dat,ifelse(y >= 0,'Above','Below'))
```

I'd like to take this basic plot:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_violin(data = dat,aes(x = factor(x),y = y))
```

and simply have each violin colored differently above and below zero. The naive thing to try, mapping the `fill` aesthetic, splits and dodges the violin plots:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_violin(data = dat,aes(x = factor(x),y = y, fill = f))
```

which is not what I want. I'd like a single violin plot at each `x` value, but with the interior filled with different colors above and below zero.

Comment: Do people do this here? Find something they think is new... ask a question for it, and answer it... all for those sweet sweet internet points?

Comment: @cory Um...[yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2729/164376), yes it is. Being rude and condescending in comments, however, is generally frowned upon, just so you know. (We all do it anyway, though.)

Comment: Cool, I didn't intend to be rude. I just didn't know. I respect your sweet sweet internet points. I really do. I've upvoted you, so you get even more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one way to do this.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

#Data setup
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3,each = 100),
                  y = c(rnorm(100,-1),rnorm(100,0),rnorm(100,1)))
```

First we'll use `ggplot::ggplot_build` to capture all the calculated variables that go into plotting the violin plot:

```
p <- ggplot() + 
    geom_violin(data = dat,aes(x = factor(x),y = y))
p_build <- ggplot2::ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
```

Next, if we take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-violin.r#L112) for `geom_violin` we see that it does some specific transformations of this computed data frame before handing it off to `geom_polygon` to draw the actual outlines of the violin regions.

So we'll mimic that process and simply draw the filled polygons manually:

```
#This comes directly from the source of geom_violin
p_build <- transform(p_build,
                     xminv = x - violinwidth * (x - xmin),
                     xmaxv = x + violinwidth * (xmax - x))

p_build <- rbind(plyr::arrange(transform(p_build, x = xminv), y),
                 plyr::arrange(transform(p_build, x = xmaxv), -y))
```

I'm omitting a small detail from the source code about duplicating the first row in order to ensure that the polygon is closed.

Now we do two final modifications:

```
#Add our fill variable
p_build$fill_group <- ifelse(p_build$y >= 0,'Above','Below')
#This is necessary to ensure that instead of trying to draw
# 3 polygons, we're telling ggplot to draw six polygons
p_build$group1 <- with(p_build,interaction(factor(group),factor(fill_group)))
```

And finally plot:

```
#Note the use of the group aesthetic here with our computed version,
# group1
p_fill <- ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data = p_build,
                 aes(x = x,y = y,group = group1,fill = fill_group))
p_fill
```

[image]

Note that in general, this will clobber nice handling of any categorical x axis labels. So you will often need to do the plot using a continuous x axis and then if you need categorical labels, add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found that splitting the data density above and below the y-axis allowed `geom_ribbon()` to plot two fill colors cleanly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

set.seed(42)
mean <- 103
sd <- 3.84

df_dens <-
    tibble(
        x = seq(90,116,.1),
        dens = dnorm(x, mean=mean, sd=sd)
  ) %>% 
   mutate(
       upper_dens = dens/2,
       lower_dens = -1*dens/2,
       myfill = ifelse(x > 100, '#54b709', '#bd0707')
    )
```

```
df_dens %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, ymin = lower_dens, ymax = upper_dens, fill = myfill)) +
    geom_ribbon() +
    scale_fill_identity() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(20)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = NULL) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()
    ) +
      labs(y = NULL)
```

[image]