# Violin plot with multiple colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I want to generate a violin plot, in which, the different regions are filled with different colors.
As an example:

```
df <- data.frame("data" = runif(1000))
ggplot(df, aes(x ="DATA", y = data)) + geom_violin(aes(fill = if_else(data > 0.5, "green","red")))
```

The commands above generate the violin plot shown in the picture below. The violin plot consists of 2 separated parts. I was expecting one complete shape (i.e. no physical separation) where the upper part (data >0.5) is colored green and the lower part is colored red.

I know there is a coloring problem. But, what I want to ask is:

- Why the plot comes in 2 separated parts?
- Is there a way to make it a single "body" as it would be in a regular violin plot?

I found the following solution have a multi-colored violin plot but it did not work in my case: [Fill specific regions in geom_violin plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203195/fill-specific-regions-in-geom-violin-plot)

Thank you.

[image: Violin Plot]

Comment: I don't think you can easily do that with a simple violinplot: either all `fill=` is the same (for a single violin) or there is no `fill=` (hollow). If you try to split the data pre-violin, then your violins will look different, so that won't work. You may need to generate your own (rotated) density curves and use two calls to `geom_polygon` to color them separately. (That may be more effort and fragility than it is worth ...)

Comment: You get two violins because you specify color inside `aes()`. This makes ggplot think it's a variable consisting of the two levels green and red, so it plots it as such. If you remove `aes()`, you instead get an error, because `geom_violin()` is only expecting one color. The method in the link you provided seems like your best choice for doing what you want.

Comment: @r2evans that was the approach I went for. It seems easier and neater than joran's answer in the linked question.

Comment: I agree that your answer is addressing the OP's request fairly well. My only concern would be if the OP actually wants to group it in a way where your current solution is not supporting ... which is one (perhaps only) advantage to joran's approach. @AllanCameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer shows a neat way to do this by building the plot and adjusting the underlying grobs, but if you want to do this without grob-hacking, you will need to get your own density curves and draw them with polygons:

```r
df <- data.frame("data" = runif(1000))

dens <- density(df$data)
new_df1 <- data.frame(y = c(dens$x[dens$x < 0.5], rev(dens$x[dens$x < 0.5])),
                      x = c(-dens$y[dens$x < 0.5], rev(dens$y[dens$x < 0.5])),
                      z = 'red2')
new_df2 <- data.frame(y = c(dens$x[dens$x >= 0.5], rev(dens$x[dens$x >= 0.5])),
                      x = c(-dens$y[dens$x >= 0.5], rev(dens$y[dens$x >= 0.5])),
                      z = 'green3')

ggplot(rbind(new_df1, new_df2), aes(x, y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0, expand = c(1, 1), labels = 'DATA', name = '')
```

[image]